# Properly closing custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I'd like to easily display custom-style popups across the whole application. 
For that in my `Utils` class I created this static method:

```
public static Dialog showStyledPopup(Context context, String sHeader, String sMessage, 
            String sBtn0Text, View.OnClickListener onClick0,
            String sBtn1Text, View.OnClickListener onClick1,
            String sBtn2Text, View.OnClickListener onClick2)
    {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.dialog_style_no_bg);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        TextView txtHeader = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_popup_header);
        if (null == sHeader)
        {
            txtHeader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else
        {
            txtHeader.setText(sHeader);
            txtHeader.setTypeface(App.fontHeader);
        }
        TextView txtMessage = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.txt_popup_message);
        txtMessage.setText(sMessage);
        txtMessage.setTypeface(App.fontCommon);
        Button btn0 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_0);
        btn0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn0.setText(sBtn0Text);
        btn0.setTypeface(App.fontCommon);
        btn0.setOnClickListener(onClick0);
        if (null != onClick1)
        {
            Button btn1 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_1);
            btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn1.setText(sBtn1Text);
            btn1.setTypeface(App.fontCommon);
            btn1.setOnClickListener(onClick1);
        }
        if (null != onClick2)
        {
            Button btn2 = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_popup_2);
            btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn2.setText(sBtn2Text);
            btn2.setTypeface(App.fontCommon);
            btn2.setOnClickListener(onClick2);
        }
        dialog.show();
        return dialog;
    }
```

popup.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_250_170"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_popup_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/group_popup_btns"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_popup_0"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_60_40"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_popup_1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_60_40"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_popup_2"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_60_40"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/group_popup_btns"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_popup_header"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" >
        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll_popup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_popup_message"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

in styles.xml:

```
<style name="dialog_style_no_bg"  parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

The caller is supposed to pass the View.OnClickListeners.
To be able to close the dialog, the caller must have `Dialog dialog` field which is then used in the OnClickListener to dismiss the dialog, e.g.:

```
this.dialog = Utils.showStyledPopup(this, null, getString(R.string.STR_ENABLE_SOUND_AND_MUSIC_Q), 
                    getString(R.string.STR_YES), new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            doToggleSound();
                            doToggleMusic();
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            dialog = null;
                        }
                    }, getString(R.string.STR_NO), new View.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            dialog = null;
                        }
                    });
```

The problem is that for some reason in rare cases the dialog field gets reset while the popup is still shown. I can't reproduce this, but got a few crash reports because of this in the field.

Has someone tried to do the same?

The activity has it's orientation fixes to landscape, so `onCreate` should never get called in-between to reset `dialog` variable.

I don't like the idea of storing the reference to the dialog, but there is just no way to use a `final` variable in this case, because it gets a value *after* it should be passed to the OnClickListener.

My question is similar to [Android close custom dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258162/android-close-custom-dialog) but the problem there is also not solved, at least as I want it (as 1 method in Utils).

I've seen `onCreate()` being called on DellStreak device at weird times, so this might be just some device-specific issue (PMP5080BRU)

Comment: Why would you do this instead of just extending the dialog class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to declare `Dialog dialog` as class field, declare it at class level.

**EDIT**
Try this solution too. Have the dialog as class field in the Utils class. Do not return the dialog object from the method, instead use it to initialize the dialog variable. The use a getter method (or try accessing directly though not recommended) of dialog variable. This is kinda dirty solution, but it might work for you too.

Comment: PS: The problem in the another question was solved, the asker was using Dialog, instead of dialog to dismiss.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what I am doing: this.dialog = ... is the class field. But the problem is that it sometimes gets reset!

Comment: So what the exception is? If it resets, then it must be throwing a NullPointerException. Also do you need to make the dialog non-cancellable?

Comment: Ah yes, kind of dirty but will do)) Extra method Utils.dismissPopup which will just dismiss the currently open dialog. I'll store dialog as private static variable. Thus the caller won't have to deal with anything except showCustomPopup() and then dismissPopup(). Can also auto-close the previously open dialog before showing a new one in case the caller forgets. This doesn't allow showing 2 dialogs at once, but that's ok for my case

Comment: Excellent addition!! That's why they call it dirty, cause it makes our life easier ;)